# firewall on ubuntu 16.04 ptpp (or openvpn) server

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, openvpn, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed and configured a PTPP server on Ubuntu 16.04 on a VPS to connect my two routers with dynamic public ip. I would like the two LAN could see each other.

```
VPS Public IP 5.5.5.5
VPN Network 10.100.100.0/24
VPN Server address 10.100.100.100
```

Router 1

```
VPN client: 10.100.100.1
LAN: 10.1.1.0/24
Router local ip: 10.1.1.1
```

Router 2

```
VPN client: 10.100.100.2
LAN: 10.2.2.0/24
Router local ip: 10.2.2.1
```

**The pc with ip address 10.2.2.55 on LAN2 should be able to reach the pc with ip address 10.1.1.33 on LAN1.**

On the VPS (ubuntu server 16.04) what are the Firewall Policy, NAT and Routing rules I should setup?

On the Router 1 and 2 what are the firewall policy, nat and routing rules I should set up?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use PPTP. It's obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore, and especially not newly deployed.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If I use openvpn the firewall setting on the Ubuntu server should be the same?